# Permission denied when running sail up

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I've installed laravel 8 and sail, but when I try to run sail up I get this error

```
vendor/bin/sail: line 14: /home/cerb/projects/timeless-treasures/vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail: Permission denied
```

Comment: can you share your docker-compose.yml file?

Answer (score 3):

I was running ubuntu on WSL2 and sail up was giving me this permission denied error. You can open your linux/wsl terminal and go one directory up using `cd ..` then try

```
chmod -R 775 <project directory name>
```

this will grant all permissions to your project directory and sail up will start working.